# Plot 2D topographic map of EEG node network on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, networking, dictionary

I would like to plot a topographic map from EEG network. The electrodes (nodes) have a associated networks metric and from these values I want to interpolate between them and plot in a head shape. Here is the code that i have reseached and the result that I am getting...

=========================================

```
%The position X and Y as integers (electrodes position) and the value of Z (network metric)

X = [36 51  66  11  22  51  79  91  3   16  51  86  99  1   14  51  88  101 3   16  51  86  99  11  22  51  79  91  36  51  66];

Y = [99 101 99  80  85  87  85  80  66  69  70  69  66  51  51  51  51  51  36  33  32  33  36  22  17  15  17  22  3   1   3];

Z = [-404   -566    -379    -71 -102    -119    -87 9   -62 -160    -104    -81 -26 12  -120    -176    -85 -13 0   -118    -288    -159    -36 -115    -145    -292    -215    -266    -235    -364    -192];

%Making the meshgrid

for dd = 1:31   
    I(Xd(dd),Yd(dd))=Zd(dd);    
end


Zd = [Zd; zeros(70,1)];

Xd = [Xd; zeros(70,1)];

Yd = [Yd; zeros(70,1)];

[XX,YY] = meshgrid(1:101,1:101);

z = griddata(Xd,Yd,Zd,XX,YY,'cubic');

contourf(z)
```

=========================================

The resulting plot of this code is

http://s16.postimg.org/s7a627s5h/Graph.jpg

I would like some help to remove this "tail" from my graph and a sugggestion of how to draw a head + nose on the same picture (only if it is possible to plot this kind of graph).

Comment: I suggest you take a look at [EEGLab](http://sccn.ucsd.edu/eeglab/), more precisely the [topoplot](http://sccn.ucsd.edu/eeglab/allfunctions/topoplot.html) function.

Comment: I have tried already, but usually I have just the cartesian coordinates of electrodes, not all information of EEG.chanlocs

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment above but you can set your own custom locations in EEGlab as far as I remember. Have you looked at the function writelocs? Maybe that helps. EEGlab's topoplots include nose and ears.

http://sccn.ucsd.edu/eeglab/allfunctions/writelocs.html